# How to format [decimal?] when it's null?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my class `partData` the `FW_Step` attribute  isfrom the type  double?

When I try to format it like that

```
partData.FW_Step.Value.ToString("F3")
```

It's fail when the value is null

How can I use the format when the value is null?

Comment: What's your question? How to use a .Value.ToString("F3"); on null?

Comment: What result are you waiting for? Please give more precisions in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't format when it's null; hopefully the reasons why are obvious.  You need to check for the value first:

```
string formattedValue;
if (partData.FW_Step.HasValue)
    formattedValue = partData.FW_Step.Value.ToString("F3");
else
    formattedValue = "default value for null";
```

You can make this code shorter using a ternary expression:

```
string formattedValue = partData.FW_Step.HasValue ? partData.FW_Step.Value.ToString("F3") : "default value for null";
```